# Is there a BottomNavigationBar type widget that supports horizontal scrolling

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a flutter widget very much like a `BottomNavigationBar`, but I need it to be able to scroll left and right, so it can handle more icons.

For instance, it may hold 12 icons in total, but only show 5. Then swipe right to left to see more icons.

Does anyone know of a widget that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TabBar in the Bottom Navigator for this

```
  bottomNavigationBar: 
  TabBar(tabs: [
  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.add),),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.seven_k),),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.wallet_giftcard_sharp),),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.ten_k),),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.phone),),],
    isScrollable: true,),
```